# set a colorscheme for a filetype in vim

Tags: vim

Within vim, I am trying to use a special colorscheme for some filetypes using an autocmd. Strangely, that does not work for all the filetypes. Here is my vimrc:

```
autocmd filetype troff :colorscheme troff
autocmd filetype tintin :colorscheme troff
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tt set ft=tintin
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tr set ft=troff
```

While openning f.tr, the colorscheme "troff" is used, but while openning f.tt, while the filetype is correctly set to "tintin", the default colorscheme is used. If I manually set the filetype (sef ft=tintin), then the colorscheme troff is loaded. Could you please help me to figure what could cause that strange behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem. However I would suggest the following auto commands:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tt let g:tmpcolor=g:colors_name            
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tr let g:tmpcolor=g:colors_name            
autocmd BufEnter *.tt colorscheme troff | set ft=tintin                  
autocmd BufEnter *.tr colorscheme troff | set ft=troff                   
autocmd BufLeave *.tt exe 'colorscheme '.g:tmpcolor                     
autocmd BufLeave *.tr exe 'colorscheme '.g:tmpcolor
```

This will create a variable `g:tmpcolor` that stores the original color scheme. When you edit a file of type `.tt` or `.tr` the color scheme will change to `troff`. When you leave these files, the color scheme will change to `g:tmpcolor`.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the problem either. The colorscheme was loaded in both cases (though for some reason `:colo` would still print `default`).

Comment: Thank you both for your answer. The fact you can't reproduce proves that the problem does not come from my vim script -- which is yet something :/